# NSString with garbage

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I am setting some value(simple format of timestamp), to my object and creating a  NSData.

```
request. processoorigem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [format stringFromDate:dt]];
```

but after pass this line and create the NSData, myObj just create my xml and return the string.

```
NSString * str = [myObj createXml:request];
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I print(NSLog) the data and get the hex and convert to string.
My xml have some garbage like this: ï¿¼ï¿¼

```
<processoorigem>ï¿¼ï¿¼1711151149170049</processoorigem>
```

I don`t know why, How I can remove this garbage?

Comment: There are just a few steps that you are leaving out. Most likely you are interpreting something wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729 no, when I print str, my xml are ok, when I use dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, and get the hex and converto to string, my xml appears with this caracters ï¿¼ï¿¼.

Comment: How are you doing this step: *get the hex and converto to string*?

Comment: Guess: Your date format includes month or day names (not numbers), which are localized to include non-ASCII characters.  The method you are using to decode the hex data from the NSData conversion assumes ASCII.